# PHP Take TEXTAREA value and turn into Comma Separated List

Tags: php

I'm taking a TEXTAREA value and I need it to always be in the same format for every input.

This is what I have tested from the codes provided in answers:

```
$tags = mysql_real_escape_string(strip_tags($purifier->purify($_POST['tags'])));
$tags = preg_replace('/\W/',' ', $tags);
$tags = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $tags);
$tags = trim($tags);
$tags = explode(' ', $tags);
$tags = array_unique($tags);
$tags = implode(',', $tags);

$tagstoadd = mb_strtolower($tags);
```

The output of anything they insert should be

'tag,tag,tag,tag,tag,tag'

If for instance, the input is 'Tag Tag Tag, Tag, Tag'

It needs to be output as 'tag,tag,tag,tag,tag'

What I have currently adds an extra comma for spaces, which isn't what I intend, if there is already a comma. And there can't be duplicates either. How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can

1. remove all non-word characters

   ```
   $txt = preg_replace('/\W/',' ', $txt); //replace non-word into space
   $txt = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $txt); //remove extra spaces
   $txt = trim($txt);//remove trailing and heading spaces
   ```
2. convert the text into array of words

   ```
   $txt = explode(' ', $txt);
   ```
3. remove duplication

   ```
   $txt = array_unique($txt); //de-duplicated
   ```
4. purify each word ( array_map )

   ```
   $txt = array_map($your_purify_function, $txt);
   ```
5. joint words with comma

   ```
   $txt = implode(', ', $txt);
   ```

I don't know what your $purifier->purify function does, does it apply to the whole text in the begin or each tag ? Anyway, if you want to 'purify' each tag, you can do this in PHP5:

```
$your_purify_function = function($tag) use ($purifier){
                          return $purifier->purify($tag); 
                        };
```

Comment: I tested this, with the code I am about to post, and the input was <?php echo drama drama, drama, drama, <b>drama</b> romance romance, romance(line skip)romance, romance, drama, drama, and the output was lt,php,echo,drama,romance,n,nromance. This gives me what I want, since it successfully forces a list. Though, I'm going to keep experimenting first.

Comment: I noticed that if I put Romance, {Romance} they are considered different, and when the array removes duplicates, it doesn't account this.

Comment: You know what, in the grand scheme of things, I suppose duplicates won't be that big of a deal if they slip in like the one I showed above, because it would go away if submitted again.

Answer (score 0):

First Removed all the Comma and converted to "Space" and Then Replace all the Space to "Comma"

```
$csvData = implode(" ", trim($input));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Regular expression to replace all "space" into a comma.
This is a Perl regex, but it should be similar to PHP.

```
's/\s+/,/g'
```

'\s+' represents 1 or more space characters (space, tab), which will be replaced with comma

Answer (score 0):

If the user can input anything, it's going to be extremely hard to use regular expressions to separate out the individual items.

If, however, the user is only going to be using words (which will become tags), commas, and spaces, try this:

```
$string = 'blah Blah , blAh, blah, blah blah';
$results = strtolower(preg_replace('/[\s,]+/', ',', $string));
```

Which gives $results the value of:

```
"blah,blah,blah,blah,blah,blah"
```

Which can then be easily manipulated further.

Edit:

If you want to remove duplicate values, as suggested by your comment, do something like this (I'm assuming that $results holds the string):

```
$string = implode(',', array_unique(explode(',', $results)));
```

Here, I'm turning the result string into an array, based on which values are comma separated, remove all non-unique values, and then turning it back into a string.

Comment: With the update to my code I am posting, inputting <?php echo tag tag tag, tag, tag, tag <b>tag</b> returns <?php,echo,tag,tag,tag,tag,tag,tag,tag

The output does remove the spaces without adding new commas. This might accomplish what I want. However, it does not account duplicates and it does not account line skips.